# Pump sizing for slurry removal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy

on our farm we need to pump slurry from an underground tank up into an open air temporary slurry holder. I understand that to calculate the power required to pump the slurry up out of the tank is calculated using the equation:

$$ P(kW) = \frac{q \rho g h}{3.6 \times 10^6} $$

The slurry density (from online sources) is about 1400kg/m^3. The flow rate does not really matter as long as it gets from point a to b so a q value of 1m$^3$/h is fine.
The height difference between the tanks is 2m.

Using these values gives a value of:

$$\begin{align}
 P &= \frac{(1)(1400)(9.81)(2)}{3.6 \times 10^6} \\
   &= \frac{27468}{3.6 \times 10^6} \\ 
   &= 0.00763 \text{kW}
\end{align}$$

And with a motor efficiency of (lets say 75%) we require (.00763kw)/(.75) = .0102kw of power from our motor.

My question is: do i need to account for the horizontal distance in between point a and point b. the pipe run rises 2m pretty much vertically and then travels 10m on flat ground. do i need more power to get the slurry over this 10m?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will take extra power to pump the slurry along a horizontal pipe. However it's effectively impossible to calculate how much extra power is needed because there are too many unknowns.

The energy loss (the Wikipedia article describe it as heat loss) in pumping a viscous fluid along a pipe is given by the [Darcy-Weisback equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation). The trouble is that this includes a parameter (the [friction factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae)) that we don't know for your slurry. The parameter probably isn't even a constant because slurry is probably a [non-Newtonian fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid).

So I'm afaid your best option is just to try pumping the slurry and see how much power is required. If the flow rate is too low you can always increase the pipe bore. The WD equation tells us that the energy loss is inversely proportional to the diameter of the pipe.